# Yesod haskell-stack installing -fPIC

Tags: linux, haskell, cabal, archlinux, haskell-stack

This is the first time I try to install Haskell yesod but I run through some problems when I use these commands on Arch Linux

```
yesod devel
```

or

```
stack exec -- yesod devel
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libHSrts.a(Scav.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libHSrts.a(Compact.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `mblock_cache' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libHSrts.a(GCAux.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `mblock_cache' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libHSrts.a(MarkWeak.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `stg_DEAD_WEAK_info' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libCffi.a(closures.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libCffi.a(ffi64.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Exit code ExitFailure 1 while running ["ghc","-clear-package-db","-global-package-db","-hide-all-packages","-package","base","-package","Cabal-1.22.5.0","/tmp/stack16245/Setup.hs","-o","/home/romano/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/tmp-setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3","-rtsopts"] in /tmp/stack16245/
ExitFailure 1
Type help for available commands. Press enter to force a rebuild.
```

Now I am not sure why this happens but I think my database settings are wrong

Comment: How did you create your yesod project ?

Comment: I followed this guide http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart

Comment: You have to run devel command like this: `stack exec -- yesod devel`

Comment: Same sort of error     /usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libCffi.a(ffi64.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: and     Exit code ExitFailure 1 while running ["ghc","-rtsopts","-threaded","-clear-package-db","-global-package-db","-hide-all-packages","-package","base","-main-is","StackSetupShim.mainOverride","-package","Cabal-1.22.5.0","/home/romano/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs","/home/romano/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs","-o","/home/romano/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.22.5.0_ghc-7.10.3"] in /tmp/stack22219/
ExitFailure 1

Comment: What is the output of `stack build -v3` ?

Comment: stack build -v3
Invalid option `-3'

Comment: stack --numeric-version                                                                 :(
1.3.2

Comment: My bad. It's just `stack build -v`.

Comment: Too much to put it on here. I hope a pastebin link is ok: http://pastebin.com/W19s8wKj

Comment: You need to run `stack setup` inside your project first and then do the `stack build`.

Comment: Again all erors when stack setup
/usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libCffi.a(closures.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /home/romano/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3/rts/libCffi.a(ffi64.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That's weird. The last thing to do is to nuke `~/.stack` and try again. If that doesn't work, post this as issue in Stack bug tracker.

Comment: nuked ~/.stack and tried again. Error --> /
Exit code ExitFailure 1 while running ["ghc","-rtsopts","-threaded","-clear-package-db","-global-package-db","-hide-all-packages","-package","base","-main-is","StackSetupShim.mainOverride","-package","Cabal-1.22.5.0","/home/romano/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-mPHDZzAJ.hs","/home/romano/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs","-o","/home/romano/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/tmp-Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_1.22.5.0_ghc-7.10.3"] in /tmp/stack6678/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some users have come across a linker errors that seem to be dependent on the local environment, i.e. the package may compile on a different machine. The issue has been reported to be non-deterministic in some cases.

The issue may be related to the use of hardening flags in some cases, specifically those related to producing position independent executables (PIE).

In Arch Linux, the support for this is provided by the **hardening-wrapper package**. Possible workaround:

```
sudo vim /etc/hardening-wrapper.conf
```

* vim, nan, emacs or whatever editor you prefer.

Change `HARDENING_PIE=1` to `HARDENING_PIE=0`
save it.

That's it.